# BigQuery: Converting UTC to a local timestamp and group by

Tags: google-bigquery

So,

I have tested a number of functions to convert timestamps to different time zones, which works fine when looking at the data. But I can't figure out to group by the local day.

I want to group user activity by a day. I have all the data in UTC together with a time zone, and given the user activity type i would like to see a day as [2am - 2am]. I have tried something like this:

`SELECT DATETIME_SUB(DATETIME(timestamp_ts, timezone), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) as local_ts, timezone, timestamp_ts as utc_timestamp
FROM table
GROUP BY 1, 2`

I'm not sure this works. It seems like I'm only changing the presentation of the data and it's the UTC time (-2 hours) that is used to group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to group user activity by day, you should group on a date column instead of a datetime column. You can do so by truncating the datetime to date.

```
SELECT DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME_SUB(DATETIME(timestamp_ts, timezone), INTERVAL 2 HOUR), DAY) as local_dt, 
timezone, timestamp_ts as utc_timestamp FROM table GROUP BY 1, 2
```